# Windows API to trigger the time synchronization

Tags: windows, time, synchronization, ntp

Is there a windows API that would achieve the equivalent of clicking the "Update now" button in the "Date and time properties"/"Internet time" tab (opened by double clicking the clock in the taskbar)?

Is there a way to monitor when the time synchronization is triggered by windows and when it succeeds or fails?

Comment: There is documentation of the w32Time.dll interface here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-w32t/0e425c15-8ae4-4c2a-b431-84a66b92986a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no API exposed by the time service, but to trigger a time synchronization you can use the `w32tm` command line tool.

In C/C++ you can do something like this:

```
include <process.h>

...

system("w32tm /resync /nowait");
```

Take a look at [w32tm documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263.aspx) for further options.

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, but better than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: if you get `The following error occurred: The service has not been started. (0x80070426)` execute `net start w32time`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClockResync
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("w32time.dll")]
        public static extern uint W32TimeSyncNow([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]String computername, bool wait, uint flag);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(W32TimeSyncNow("computername", true, 8).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It's undocumented so I'm not exactly sure what the possible flags are, but 8 seems to do the job just fine - tested with my system clock. If you're running Windows 64-bit, compile for 64-bit or you'll be getting access violation exceptions.

`W32TimeQueryStatus` should be able to get the last successful sync time. I'll work on that when I have more time.

Comment: thats not C++, thats C#